# Radiobutton(only Single selection) inside RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, radio-button, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am using a `heterogeneous recyclerview` that contains RadioButton(Only single selection)

But my code doesn't gives me the proper output

After many clicks it does't gives me checked state of the radiobutton

```
public class RadioLayout extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
                @Bind(R.id.rd_group)
                RadioGroup rdGroup;
                @Bind(R.id.radio_question)
                RadioButton rdQuestion;

                public RadioLayout(View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
                        rdQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                        if(previousPos!=getLayoutPosition()){

                                                list.get(previousPos).isChecked=false;
                                                notifyItemChanged(previousPos);
                                        }
                                        list.get(getLayoutPosition()).isChecked=true;
                                        notifyItemChanged(getLayoutPosition());
                                        previousPos=getLayoutPosition();
                                }
                        });

                }


@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                final EmployeeRecyclerModel model = list.get(position);
                try {
                        if (holder instanceof RadioLayout) {
                                final RadioLayout headerHolder = (RadioLayout) holder;
                                headerHolder.rdQuestion.setText(model.answers);

                                if(model.isChecked) {
                                        headerHolder.rdQuestion.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                else{
                                        headerHolder.rdQuestion.setChecked(false);
                                }
```

Comment: What is the proper output supposed to be?

Comment: Only one radiobutton selectable out of 4 or more